# Inserting singular items into repeating grids

Tags: css, django

I am building a 2-column grid layout for a Q&A page.  I'm using Django and each question is looped over.  I'm trying to place an **Ask Question** button in the `top2` class.  I only want one **Ask Question** button, and right now there is a button for every question.

My question is, how do I insert a singular item into a repeating grid like this?

django - template

```
{% for question in questions %}
<div class="top">
    <div class="top1">
        # Stuff here...
    </div>
    <div class="top2">
        <form action="{% url 'question_ask' %}">
            <button class="button3"><span>Ask question</span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

CSS

```
.top {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `forloop.first` variable
about many other read in [docs for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
{% for question in questions %}
<div class="top">
    <div class="top1">
        # Stuff here...
    </div>
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="top2">
            <form action="{% url 'question_ask' %}">
                <button class="button3"><span>Ask question</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can't believe I did not know about this, now a whole new world of opportunities have opened up.  Thanks!

Comment: glad to help you